# <cms:include without <p> tag

Tags: java, jsp, opencms

Is there any solution to have something like `<cms:include type="OpenCmsString" element="text1" />` ? Because the output from my `<cms:include element="text1">` always give me data with `<p>` tag.

Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've once created my own tag for that (StripPTag). You would compile that class and wrap it in a jar file, then deploy that to your opencms webapp lib folder.

```
package com.opencmsserver.taglib;

import org.opencms.flex.CmsFlexController;
import org.opencms.jsp.Messages;
import org.opencms.main.CmsLog;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

/**
 * Removes the <p> tag from the surrounded content, 
 * because FCKEditor always add <p> tag to content at 
 * the beginning and end when using the html editor component  
 *
 * @author  Mathias Lin 
 * 
 * @version $Revision: 0.1 $ 
 * 
 * @since 0.4 
 */
public class StripPTag extends BodyTagSupport {

    /** Serial version UID required for safe serialization. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2361021288258405388L;

    /** The log object for this class. */
    private static final Log LOG = CmsLog.getLog(StripPTag.class);


    /**
     * @see javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag#doEndTag()
     * @return EVAL_PAGE
     * @throws JspException in case soemthing goes wrong
     */
    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {

        ServletRequest req = pageContext.getRequest();

        // This will always be true if the page is called through OpenCms 
        if (CmsFlexController.isCmsRequest(req)) {
            try {
                // Get link-string from the body and reset body 
                String content = getBodyContent().getString();
                content = content.replaceAll("<p>", "");
                content = content.replaceAll("</p>", "");
                getBodyContent().clear();
                getBodyContent().print(content);
                getBodyContent().writeOut(pageContext.getOut());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
                    LOG.error("Failed using StripPTag. ", ex);
                }
                throw new JspException(ex);
            }
        }
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }
}
```

and my own opencmsserver.tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE taglib
  PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">

<taglib>
    <tlib-version>0.1</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
    <short-name>opencmsserver</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.opencmsserver.com/taglib/cms</uri>
    <display-name>OpenCms JSP standard taglib</display-name>
    <description>
        Additional OpenCms Tags
        Developed by SYSVISION Ltd. / Mathias Lin (info@opencmsserver.com)
    </description>

    <tag>
        <name>stripPTag</name>
        <tag-class>com.opencmsserver.taglib.StripPTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>JSP</body-content>
        <description>
            This tag stripts the p-tag from the surrounded content.
        </description>
    </tag>         

</taglib>
```

which I then reference in my web.xml:

```
<!-- Begin: Custom SYSVISION OpenCmsServer lib -->      
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://www.opencmsserver.com/taglib/opencmsserver</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/opencmsserver.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

In your jsp, you just surround it then with:

```
<opencmsserver:stripPTag>Some content<p>with a paragraph</opencmsserver:stripPTag>
```

(and don't forget to reference to this tag lib in the jsp header section).